# RoR Method to search for data in a table and then update another column on another table based on that data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a program i am making changes to for my work. I know what i must do but i am having problems getting the code to work. I come from a Java and C background.

i have two tables one table called customprojecschedule_lines has a project_id,workorder_base_id, and other various columns column.

The other table called customschedule has an id, workorder column and various other columns.

I have a method and variable called work order.

I am trying to get an SQL statement that will do that like this:

```
class Customschedule < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "customschedules" 
after_create :build_customprojectschedule_lines
has_many :customprojectschedule_lines, :dependent => :destroy

has_one :projectschedule_cost
delegate :est_cost, :act_cost, :to => :projectschedule_cost, :allow_nil => true

attr_accessor :workorder_base, :lots

def workorder
customschedule.where(:id => customprojectschedule_lines.product_id)
end

 def workorder=(wo)
@workorder_base = wo
customprojectschedule_lines.each do |pl|
  pl.update_attributes({:workorder_base_id => wo})
 end
end

def build_customprojectschedule_lines
lines = @lots.split(',').inject([]) do |lines, lot_id|
  line = customprojectschedule_lines.find_or_initialize_by_workorder_lot_id(lot_id)
  if line.new_record?
    p workorder_base
    line.workorder_base_id = @workorder_base
    line.line_no = lot_id
    line.workorder_split_id = 0
  end
  lines << line
end
customprojectschedule_lines.replace(lines)
end
```

Basically what i would like is that whenever a user enters a workorder on the form number goes into the database gets the stored values with that record and then retrieves the ID(from that record) and puts that same id in my other table.

However, i keep getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `customschedule' for #          
<Customschedule:0x00000005542040>
```

Before when i was trying things i kept getting a weird looking select statement saying that Customschedule ID was null.

We use oracle here.

This is my first time posting on here so please let me know if i need anything else.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to upcase the first letter in this line

```
customschedule.where(:id => customprojectschedule_lines.product_id)
```

change it to

```
Customschedule.where(:id => customprojectschedule_lines.product_id)
```